# How do you pass an object to a windsor container instead of a type?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have the following class:

```
public class ViewPage<TView,TPresenter> : Page 
    where TView : IView
    where TPresenter : Presenter<TView>
{
    public ViewPage()
    {
        if (!(this is TView))
            throw new Exception(String.Format("The view must be of type {0}", typeof(TView)));

        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddComponent("view", typeof(IView), typeof(TView));
        container.AddComponent("presenter", typeof(Presenter<TView>), typeof(TPresenter));
        TPresenter presenter = container[typeof(TPresenter)] as TPresenter;
    }
}
```

and this is the Presenter code:

```
public class Presenter<T> where T : IView
{
    public T View { get; private set; }

    public Presenter(T view)
    {
        this.View = view;
    }
}
```

I'd like to pass the current instance of `ViewPage` to `TPresenter` via `Windsor` instead of having it instantiate a new object. 
How can i achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: This is the oldest question on SO still without any answer I could find.